# When using cnosdb, why does the join statement fail?

Tags: cnosdb

I am using cnosdb on my Mac laptop, I loaded this sample data:
https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/files/10083169/oceanic_station_20w.txt

I try to execute join statement:

```
SELECT * FROM air INNER JOIN sea ON sea.station = air.station;
```

but failed:

```
error sending request for url (http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?tenant=cnosdb&db=public&chunked=false): connection closed before message completed

Caused by:
    connection closed before message completed
```

How can I solve this problem?

What configuration should I adjust?